# The tool for visual programming

Tags: lisp, visual-programming, graphical-programming

I need the tool for graphical representing of work flow in a program (like electronic circuits are described with graphical representation). The representation has to be like the following: functions are boxes and arrows between boxes are "messages". Like this:

[alt text http://img372.imageshack.us/img372/8471/functionsqv0.png](http://img372.imageshack.us/img372/8471/functionsqv0.png)

This picture shows the following: (c (a) (b))
Where parameters of c() are named as d and e. On C it would be

```
void c( someType1 d, someType2 e );
someType1 a( void );
someType2 b( void );
....
c( a(), b() );
```

So I think that I need the tool for manipulation and visual representation of s-expressions like these:

```
(a (b c d) e)
```

or

```
f(g(z(x,y))+5)
```

It is not about linked lists, it is about logical connections between functions.
The tool has only to generate the textual representation from graphical one.
Well, I've found a lot of stuff on the Wiki page about the "Visual programming" and "Graphical programming" and so on. Mostly all described tools are cool, but somewhat complicated. And the list is pretty long, so it would take a lot of time to test all of them. So I need an opinion of real, alive people.

Requirements are:

- Free
- Simple
- Can export to at least one real
  language like XML or C++ or LISP or any
  other.

And it would be really good if this tool were configurable.

I like the FlowDesigner tool: it seems to be almost the thing I need, but it cannot export to any language... Alas.

**UPD**: The wiki page I mentioned: [Graphical Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_programming)
**UPD2**: well, I decided to write my own tool...

Comment: provide a link to the "the Wiki page", I am interested

Comment: I am studying Lisp.  The second S-expr you provide contains "x,y" which I find curious because of the comma.  Lisp usually uses whitespace like in your first S-expr.

Comment: I don't get it.  The answer seems to be "a keyboard" and "a screen".

Comment: 2Mark Stock: it's just a different syntax for (f (+ (g (z x y)) 5)). It's not too special or interesting.
2Harleqin: well, why then electronic circuits are drawn with symbols but not represented in text form? I mean not the physical but logical stuff.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Would you like a tool where you can draw e.g. box-and-pointer diagrams (http://www.xcf.berkeley.edu/~jmacd/envdraw/node2.html)?

Comment: 2Jonas: thank you for your question, I tried to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using something like [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)?

Answer (score 3):

Check out Microsoft DSL Tools - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126259.aspx

It is a "designer generator" - allows you to define your own diagram format, specify shapes, arrows, colors, etc. and generates a designer for you that is able to edit such diagrams and export any textual artifacts about your diagram (e.g. XML or code).

Comment: Is there any working example?  
The solution seems to be kinda general for my task.

Comment: Sorry, I just cannot get through these docs: it's an overwhelming volume and it seems to be a middle of some solution of some task (DSL)...

Comment: This might be a better starting point:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DSLToolsLab

Comment: Gotta second this. DSL tools just rock. Difficult to get started, but once you start rolling... well... the fun never ends.

Answer (score 2):

*Warning: Shameless plug*

Seen [Memention Designer](http://www.memention.com/designer)?

It's built around a configurable engine and can output in almost any language.

But, I'm sorry. It's not really free.

[image]
<sub>(source: [memention.com](http://www.memention.com/designer/desscreen.jpg))</sub>

Above example exports following c-code, but could with some re-configuration generate some else language.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* there are 8 blocks */
int running;
/* there are 1 out blocks */
int state_curr_1;
int state_next_1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  running = 1;
  state_curr_1 = 0;
  while (running) {
    state_next_1 = (state_curr_1 + 19);
    running = (state_curr_1 != (19 * 12));
    state_curr_1 = state_next_1;
    printf("out = %d\n", state_curr_1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.graphviz.org/

HTH

Answer (score 1):

What abou using the .net and WPF based library [TUM.CMS.VPLControl](https://github.com/tumcms/TUM.CMS.VPLControl)?

[image]